# My poor minifig's head is stuck in his helmet!

Tags: minifigures, disassembly

Recently I made a LEGO race car with a driver who wore a helmet. Unfortunately, after the race, I tried to take off his helmet and his head came off inside the helmet. Any suggestions about getting it out so he can see again?

Comment: Can you post a photograph of this so that we can understand the problem better?

Comment: @AndersonGreen The sugar liquid answer by awe worked.

Comment: My Skull Sorcerer figure’s head keeps getting stuck inside the helmet. I bought the latest Ninjago magazine which includes a spare Skull Sorcerer figure but that figure’s head gets stuck inside the helmet too! Does everyone who owns this figure have this problem or is it just my bad luck?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use some sugar liquid to use as temporary glue to make the head stuck to the torso. Then wait till the sugar is sticky and then try to remove the helmet. Once the helmet is loose you can put the head and torso in warm water to loosen the sugar glue and take it off. Then wash thoroughly to remove remaining sugar.

Comment: I wonder if someone sells some premade easy-to-disolve glue, but an homemade solution sounds even better

Answer (score 12):

A trick that's worked for me in the past, is to use a 1x1 cone with a Technic axle in it (it needs to be the cone [without the top groove](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=4589), unlike the example below) - this will allow you to force the tapered end of the cone into the hole on the bottom of the head, and by fastening a Technic gearwheel, brick or larger cylinder to the Technic axle, you'll be able to apply a fair amount of force to increase the clutch of the cone piece in the head and twist to loosen it from the helmet with a push-twist-pull movement. Good luck.

[image: Part 4589b Cone 1 x 1 without Top Groove]
[image: Technic Axle]
[image: Large Technic Gear]
[image: Part 6222 Brick, Round 4 x 4 with Holes]

Answer (score 8):

Your problem is that the clutch (what holds bricks together) between the helmet and the head is too high, and in any case higher than the clutch between head and torso.

This means the solution is to increase the clutch between the head and another part you'll use to remove it. I would first recommend trying other torsos, maybe one has enough clutch to easily take the head with it and beat the helm. Twisting the parts while trying to separate them should also help.

If that fails, other LEGO parts might help, but I'm not sure which ones - torsos have a longer stud probably for that very reason. Maybe a Technic pin with friction?

You could also try slipping some paper around a torso stud, but be careful not to just push the paper alone inside the head.

Comment: Unfortunately, his head's still stuck.

Answer (score 8):

A quick and easy way to remove a helmet stuck onto the head...I used a piece of Bounty kitchen roll, approximately 3cm x 3cm, (which is actually thicker then a single ply toilet tissue) and placed this over the stub of the body then pushed the head onto this.  The head will not go all the way down, but far enough for it to remain firmly in place.  Then I was able to remove the helmet very easily.

Comment: Kitchen towel did the trick for me. Just adds enough clutch for the torso to grab the head.

Answer (score 6):

You need to get something into the head-hole to grip the head whilst you remove the helmet.

You could try a pair of snap-ring pliers or needle nose pliers. Insert both jaws into the hole and pull them apart as much as possible whilst you remove the head from the helmet. You might need a helper - someone to remove the helmet whilst you grip the head with the tool.

You may not be able to avoid scratching the inside of the head-hole slightly - but a scratch where it won't be seen is probably better than throwing two parts away.

Worst case, you write-off the head completely, but at least you've still got a useful helmet. If you do get to the point where you can't remove the helmet without damaging it, you could resort to super-gluing something to the inside of the head and pull it out.

Answer (score 6):

Take some scotch tape and wrap it round the neck thing. Then you just put the head on and pull the helmet off. If that doesn't work, use more tape, it will make the head stay on the neck a little better.

Answer (score 6):

I just removed a non-LEGO crown which was very very tight top on Nadakhan's head. It was so tight, it seemed that only destroying it could help. But my son loved the crown and especially head, so here is my solution:

1. I put some olive oil between the crown and the head
2. I took a paper napkin and put it over a LEGO torso's neck
3. I put the head stuck on the neck over the paper, so the head was pretty tight on the torso
4. I boiled some water, poured it into a cup, then holding the minifigure's legs, put the crown in the boiling water. Please note - not the head, just the helmet (crown in my case)!
5. After about 2 minutes held in the very hot water (I hoped the hot water would expand the crown, but not the head. I don't know if this step was really necessary), I could completely remove the crown from the head with pliers.

Good luck to everyone with the same problem :)

Answer (score 5):

You should try to use a torso that is really, really gripping. The newer, the better. Do you have any Exo-Force minifigures? I found those torsos really, really tight. Whenever I got something stuck, I always plonk them on Hikaru's torso. Works most of the time. Helps if you twist it around. Once the helmet turns but the head doesn't, you're gold.

Comment: Okay, this would be good for in the future if it happens again.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is going to sound weird, but wrap a piece of single-ply toilet paper over the neck of the body piece. Jam that in the head's hole and twist until the face starts to move. Then pull. The head should come out of the helmet no problem!

Answer (score 4):

You can also try to use soapy water. You know how people use soap to remove a stuck ring from their finger? The same works for stuck LEGO helmets. Just immerse the helmet/head in some water with lots of soap, then do as Joubarc mentioned; attach them back to a torso, and now wiggle off the helmet...(c:

Comment: It wiggles but it won't come out. The neck keeps slipping out of the head before the helmet comes off of the head.

Answer (score 4):

Just, let the time goes by, that happenned to me with a dwarf beard, I had to wait 2 months, and after that, it came off easily. In your case, I need that Anakin's hair just gets stuck in it's head.

Answer (score 4):

You can put a little bit of 2 sided tape on the neck of the torso and stick it in the head and pull and it works, however this may get stuck inside the head. So using one sided tape would work if you put enough layers on....also 1 sided tape is easier to to get hold of.

Comment: Yeah, and what if some of the tape gets stuck inside the head hole after? I think this approach sounded risky...

Answer (score 4):

Take a household screw slightly wider than the hole inside the head. Screw it in until the threads feel a bit tight. Then pull it out with a pliers. If you have a screw but it's not wide enough inside the neck, wrap it in a paper towel and screw it in till it's tight and will make the head turn inside the helmet, and then pull it out.

Answer (score 3):

You could always use a tight torso and put it inside the head. I actually used mega block brand legs to take out the head of my minfig. Sometimes it doesn't work but most of the time it does.

Comment: Needless to say, you don't even need clone-brands for this. I have an official lego torso for the passenger train set and his is **really** tight. But I suppose thats not very common.

Answer (score 3):

Put the head (with the helmet stuck on) on a torso. As you take the helmet off, bend the helmet a little.

As long as there is more friction between the torso and head than the head and helmet it should come of with some effort.

Answer (score 3):

You can put some duct tape on top of a LEGO axle and push it into the head hole and twist until it comes out!

Answer (score 3):

Grab a sharp knife. Stick it inside the head on a slight angle and twist the helmet off. This has worked every time for me. :) Just be careful when you do it!

Comment: Wouldn't the knife edge damage the head with this method?

Answer (score 3):

I boiled some water. Then I stuck a pencil eraser in the head. After that I dipped mostly just the helmet in the water. Finally, I attached the head to the torso and kept on twisting the helmet until it got loose and fell off.

I hope this works for someone else!