# HELP ! Darth Maul stuck in glue?

Tags: star-wars, glue

Not so long ago I got my hands on a box full of loose bricks. There I found an old minifigure head of Darth Maul BUT stuck in his hood! I'm 100% sure it's glue. Is there anything I can do about it ?

Comment: If you are sure it is glue, what kind of glue is it?

Comment: So you want to separate the head and the hood? *Is there anything I can do about it ?* is a very open question, so it's unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 4):

To paraphrase an [answer from @awe](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/2331/my-poor-minifigs-head-is-stuck-in-his-helmet/2336#2336) on a similar question,

> You can use some sugar liquid as temporary glue to make the head stuck to the torso. Wait until the sugar is sticky and then pull off the helmet. Once the helmet is loose,  put the head and torso in warm water to remove the sugar glue.

Depending on the glue attaching the hood to the head, you might need to use some other water-soluble glue in place of sugar water glue.

Comment: I think that the OP wants to split the head and the hood, it looks like your answer is explaining how to glue the parts, not separate them.

Comment: @A.L notice that my glue is temporary, just for enough grip to pull off the hood using the torso as an anchor. It isn't glue for keeping things stuck.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. It implies that the current glue is not too strong.